# conexión mysql con flask/python

Tags: mysql, python, flask

Intento hacer un ejemplo que ví en la red con Flask y MySQL(instalé xampp sobre ubuntu 16)

En consola no saca ningún error y veo los datos que le mando imprimir para comprobar

pero cuando intento la conexión a la base de datos me da este error

MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'flaskcontacts'
mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/')
def Index():
    return render_template('index.html')

# impresión navegdor
#return ' Hello JFQ '

@app.route('/add_contact', methods=['POST'])
def add_contact():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fullname = request.form['fullname']
        phone = request.form['phone']
        email = request.form['email']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO contacts (fullname, phone, email) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)', fullname, phone, email))
        mysql.connection.commit()
    # impresión en consola funciona
    #print(fullname)
        return ' ************ RECEIVED **********'
```

Comment: ya localicé el error, en la línea app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost' hay que sustituir la palabra 'localhost' por la IP correspondiente, en mi caso 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
import pymysql

db=pymysql.connect(
            host = 'localhost',
            user = 'root',
            password = 'mysql',
            db = 'flaskcontacts'
)
app = Flask(__name__)
api = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/add_contact', methods=['POST'])
def add_contact():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fullname = request.form['fullname']
        phone = request.form['phone']
        email = request.form['email']
        
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO contacts (fullname, phone, email) VALUES (%s, %s, 
                      %s)', (fullname,phone,email))
        cursor.connection.commit()
        return 'received'
```

Espero que te ayude, a mi me funcionó
Saludos,

Comment: Una explicación sería adecuada. Puro código sin explicar el problema no ayuda mucho.

Comment: No respondes a la pregunta, que se resuelve cambiando localhost por 127.0.01.
En cambio sustituyes la librería de mysql para flask por pymysql. Si vas a utilizar pymysql no tiene sentido la línea api = MySQL(app). Además, en tu ejemplo no liberas ni la conexión ni el cursor.